# Modifying the edit method to update both models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2017

I've created 2 models for my web app - let's say Model A & Model B. I've managed to display the data for both models on a single view. My problem is I can only edit Model A. How can I modify the edit method in the controller so that I can update both models from the same view?

Here's the Edit method in the view model's controller:

```
 // GET: ABViewModel/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var modelA = await _context.ModelADetails
                .Include(i => i.ModelBDetails)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (vendor == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(modelA);
        }

        // POST: ABViewModel/Edit/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var modelAToUpdate = await _context.ABViewModel
                .Include(s => s.ModelBDetails)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.ID == id);

            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<ModelA>(
                    vendorToUpdate,
                    "",
                    i => i.FirstName, i => i.LastName, i => i.PhoneNo, i => i.Email)
            { 
                try
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
                {
                    //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                        "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                        "see your system administrator.");
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(modelAToUpdate);
        }
```

Here's the view model:

```
namespace WebAppProject.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class ModelAandB
    {
        public IEnumerable<ModelA> ModelADetails { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ModelB> ModelBDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If each model is encased in its own `<form>` element, then just point the form to the correct controller method.  If you want to adjust data from each model simultaneously, then you will need a model that encases the other two models.

Comment: @SamAxe Do you mean a view model? There is already one - please see my updated post. ModelAandB encases properties of both models.

Answer (score 1):

Create View Model That Has The Properties You Want To Update From Both Models

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
   public string FirstPropFromModel1 {get; set}
   public string SecondPropFromModel1 {get; set}
   public string FirstPropFromModel2 {get; set}
   public string SecondPropFromModel2 {get; set}
}
```

Now You When Your View Sends an Object Of This Class You Can Easily Extract The Required Value From This Object's Properties